# Metatag on field collection page

Tags: entities

I work on drupal 7, In content type add New **field** type **field collection**. Add content and use meta tag. In content page (node) meta tag display properly, In field collection page field-collection/field-name/id content display proper, we want to add meta tag (title, description, etc) of every field collection page.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module, and [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module, and the metatag content submodule thats bundled with metatag, you can assign metatags by nid or url. The problem would be that it wouldnt do this programmatically, but might be a quick fix if you havent got that many pages.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to use metatag to generate metatags based on tokens and patterns for a field collection.

Answer (score 0):

By default, metatag support is disabled for field-collection-items. You can enable it by writing your own custom module implementing `hook__metatag_entity_type_is_supported_alter()` (see below). After enabling the custom_module (or cache clear), you should be able to enable/disable metatags for field-collections under `admin/config/search/metatags/settings`. The field-collection metatag form elements won't appear on the host entity form (i.e. node form), but on the field-collection edit form.

*In my use-case I set the metatag values via the host-token to the host entity values, if an editor needs to set different values for a field collection item he needs to edit this particular item.*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_metatag_entity_type_is_supported_alter()
 *
 * Enable Metatag support for field-collection-items, to be able to set metatags
 * for gallery field-collection-items.
 */
function custom_module_metatag_entity_type_is_supported_alter(&$suitable, $entity_type, $entity_info) {
  // Enable Metatag support for field_collection_item's previously disabled in
  // metatag_entity_type_is_suitable().
  if ($entity_type == 'field_collection_item') {
    $suitable = TRUE;
  }
}
```